# ChangeImage() images to go to different links

Tags: javascript, css

I have 6 buttons, (shirt sizes) and a display window below. 
in the window below. a different image is revealed for 
each of button that's pressed. This part i figured out.

Now what I want to add is, 
for each image that is revealed, 
to have the image be a link that opens up a different link
per mage.

For example 
Buttons are for shirts size SM-XXXL
When you click on a size lets say medium, 
a picture pops up saying something like
"Alittle about our medium shirts" and
"Click here to Shop Medium Shirts" 
 I want to assign different links per image so 
a link for medium shirts when you click on the image, 
etc.

Here is what I have so far for the image selection:

With this HTML, all the images go to the same location instead of different ones:

`<a href="https://www.goggle.com"><img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="image1.jpg" style="width: 100%;" /></a>`

```
<script>
    function changeImage(click_id) {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        var img1 = document.getElementById('1');
        var img2 = document.getElementById('2');
        var img3 = document.getElementById('3');
        var img4 = document.getElementById('4');
        var img5 = document.getElementById('5');
        var img6 = document.getElementById('6');

        if (click_id == 1 ) {
            image.src = "Image1.jpg";
        } 
        else if (click_id == 2) {
            image.src = "Image2.jpg";
        }
        else if (click_id == 3) {
            image.src = "Image3.jpg";
        }
        else if (click_id == 4) {
            image.src = "image4.jpg";
        }
        else if (click_id == 5) {
            image.src = "image5.jpg";
        }
        else if (click_id == 6) {
            image.src = "image6.jpg";
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
</script></a></p>
```

Comment: You need to share code, seems like you shared code partially

Comment: Well, yeah... you aren't passing anything to your `changeImage` function, so none of the conditions will ever be hit.